# force specific text vba

Tags: excel, vba, text

Is there any way to force a user to use only specific text in a cell?
For example, I'd like a user can write in cell A1 a text by using only the following words or symbol:
"Price", "Factor", "Adder", "Main", "+","-", "(",")"
so that the user can write something like:
((Main-Price)+Adder)
but no text that includes any letter, words or symbol different from the one above

Comment: you could substitute every thing in your OK list, and replace it with "". then check the length of the text in the cell.  if its greater than 0 than you know you have some other characters left over.  HINT: you need to start your substitution from the longest thing first. and you may need to perform a clean/trim function too to get rid of spaces potentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr(), item

    arr = Array("Price", "Factor", "Adder", "Main", "+", "-", "(", ")") 'text allowed
    str = Target.Value

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 'change A1 to your range
        For Each item In arr    'replace all item in arr with ""
            str = Replace(str, item, "")
        Next item

        If Len(Trim(str)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Enter Correct Data", vbCritical, "Invalid Entry"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = vbNullString     'if incorrect data entered make cell empty
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Formard Ed suggestion, you could used `data validation` in combination with `substitute` function. Please put your list of acceptable values in range `E1:E8`. then in cell `B1` paste this function `=LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,$E$1,""),$E$2,""),$E$3,""),$E$4,""),$E$5,""),$E$6,""),$E$7,""),$E$8,"")))`.

In cell `A1` create `data validation`, set allow to `custom`, and in `formula tab` enter this formula `=B1=0`
[image]

Now if you enter wrong input in cell `A1`, data validation will not let you enter value.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the formula in data validation `=yourformula = 0` and avoid the helper column.

Comment: Tried again now and it is working, must have forgotten about =0 part :)

Comment: I would through trim in there for any spaces: `=LEN(TRIM(...`